# COALESCE types character varying and numeric cannot be matched

Tags: postgresql, coalesce

I have a table named `table1` with columns `Gender varchar(10)` and `Team numeric`.

```
create table table1 (
ID integer
Gender varchar(10),
Team numeric
);

insert into table1 (ID,Gender,Team) values
(1,'M',NULL),
(2,NULL,10),
(3,NULL,6),
(4,''F',NULL),
(5,NULL,3);
```

I will like to create a new column as `Nxt` that returns a row that is not null from any of the columns either a string or integer.

The column `Nxt` will look like: `M,10,6,F,3`

I tried this:

```
select coalesce(Gender,Team) as value from table1;
```

It returns this error:

> COALESCE types character varying and numeric cannot be matched

Comment: Cast both to strings before passing to `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 12):

Try to cast the column as text

```sql
    select coalesce(Gender,Team::text) as value from table1;
```